# How to Go from One fragment to another fragment from adapter class of first fragment using intent using Java

Tags: java, android

I wanted to go from One Fragment to another fragment from adapter class of first fragment (My first fragment contains recycler view and i am polulating it with data from realtime firebase )using intent using Java. I wanted to use intent because i wanted to start a new fragment with additional data from the adapter like userid and postid by using

```
intent.putExtra("publisherid", firebaseUser.getUid());
```

> Can you guys help me by giving some sample code steps to follow

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface

```
interface AdapterItemClickListener {
  void onItemClickListener(String publisherid)
}
```

in first fragment where is recycler view

```
 public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterItemClickListener  {
    /////another code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       ///another code
        MyAdapter  myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        //another code
        }
    
      void onItemClickListener(String publisherid) {
          SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment()
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putString("publisherid", publisherid);
          secondFragment .setArguments(args);
          FragmentTransaction ft = 
    getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, secondFragment);
    ft.commit();
       }
    }
```

Your adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmployeeViewHolder> {
         ///another variablkes
            AdapterItemClickListener itemClickListener;
        
            public MyAdapter (AdapterItemClickListener itemClickListener){
                this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
            }
            
           @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EmployeeViewHolder holder, int position) {
       
                ///another code
               
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener (v -> { 
                   itemClickListener.onItemClickListener(firebaseUser.getUid());
               });
            }

///another adapter code
}
```

second Fragment

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    ///another code
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           ///another code
            String publisherid = getArguments().getString("publisherid");
        }

    ///another code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, I would try and get back to you

Comment: what is _R.id.your_placeholder,_ in first fragment code

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` is not woking in the fragment

Comment: Throws an error in adapterclass [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kT_6-3ne67eLdlyinOYHP1x6i8Nszt0k/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: instead getSupportFragmentManager use getParentFragmentManager

Comment: R.id.your_placeholder it's example here should be fragment container from your xml, usually is framelayout id

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kT_6-3ne67eLdlyinOYHP1x6i8Nszt0k/view    what kind of error?

Comment: Line 36 after I type the code you showed, it shows some error

Comment: this is clear need description of error, try to run your project and take a look at build time error